# Securing a PHP with password as a parameter

Tags: php, security

We run a database on Windows 10 and want to be able to update customer order status on an SQL database on our website but the host does not allow computers to connect to the database.  It can only be queried through the website.

Is calling a PHP script with a strong password as a paramater safe, eg using the flow below?

Database calls the pages https://example.com/interface.php?pw=mypw&customer=mycustomer&status=1

The the PHP script will validate the PW, check the customer exists and validate the status passed is 0,1,2,3,4,5 and update the SQL accordingly?

Comment: No its not safe because everyone can read your password from your browser history.
There are already a ton of tutorials and information out there for authentication especially with php so go search for these. You should at least use hashed passwords and sessions for basic login management.

Comment: It might be ok, but it's not ideal because you passed the values on the query string instrad of headers or body. Browser history and server logs can store those values if they are on the query string. But anyway, don't re-invent the wheel...its too easy to make mistakes. for better security consider using a well known standard for authentication such as Oauth, and/or using an existing authentication / authorisation implementation from a framework such as Laravel or one of the others

Comment: Should have added, it will be called directly from the database VB code so doesn't use a browser (so presumably no browser history?) and the section is protected by htaccess using deny all except our static IP.

Comment: Even so, network logs at any point on the route can keep records of the details potentially. Seriously if you don't understand the likely pitfalls then you shouldn't be trying to write your own authentication system. Use something tried and tested. There are plenty of free API frameworks out there which provide authentication modules, as I already alluded to. Then you can get on with adding some useful functionality which is bespoke to your application, rather than doing a bad job of re-writing things which already exist.

Comment: Credentials shouldn't go into the GET parameters because GET request URLs are stored in log files. Put the credentials in appropriate headers and at best incorporate into tokens (like bearer).